# Questions involving words usage

Tags: word-usage

What proper words should I use in the following:

1) A teacher tells his students

> I am going to take a glass of water. Keep quiet, I should not hear any noise

this is the part of the sentence where I don't know which proper words to use

2) Should I use costly or costy in the following:

> Gold is a costy/costly metal.

3) If some one want to go up to the roof of the house what should he say

> I want to climb the roof

or something else.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We prefer to have just one question per post. I suggest you **boldface** the part of #1 which puzzles you, and delete #2 and #3 here. If you consult a dictionary you will find there is no word *costy* in ordinary use, so #2 would be closed; #3 may be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (1),

> I am going to take a glass of water. 
>   Keep quiet, I should not hear any noise

"Keep quiet" and "I should not hear any noise" are both independent clauses.  They should be either separated by a semicolon or separated into two sentences.  To add clarity, "*take*" should be changed to "*drink*" if that is the action being performed.  Furthermore, "*should not*" should be changed to "*do not want to*".
The correct sentences would be

> I am going to drink a glass of water.  Keep quiet; I do not want to hear any noise.

Even better, you could relate the two sentences:

> While I drink a glass of water, keep quiet; I do not want to hear any noise.

In (2),

> Gold is a costy/costly metal.

As StoneyB pointed out, *costy* is not in the dictionary.

Edit:

In (3),

> I want to climb the roof

is more descriptive when written as:

> I want to climb *up* the roof.

Comment: (3) as stated by OP is weird. It should be something like "I want to climb onto the roof" or "I want to climb up on the roof."